# Laravel and jquery ajax response

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm pushing an ajax post with jquery to e method in the controller which should return a json response but I'm not getting anything, no errors but no response either. Then end goal is broader as you will see from my ajax but for now getting that response back from the controller would be stellar

The jquery ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
            url    : "/menu/sort",
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : { menu: menu, order: order },
            success: function (data) {
                holder.html(data);
            }

        });
```

The controller action:

```
return Response::json('ok');
```

my route:

```
Route::post('menu/sort', 'MenuController@sort');
```

Comment: Did you try to put `console.log(data)` inside the `success` handler to see if you are actually receiving it and what you are receiving? Is `holder` a valid reference? Are you sure `/menu/sort` is being routed to the right controller function that has that `return Response::json('ok');`. You left out the details of the `routes.php` so can't help much with what you provided so far. I would also add an `error` handler function inside the ajax call so that if you're getting some kind of HTTP error you can see it.

Comment: I was getting an error when I had the route as expecting GET instead of PUT so I know it's going to that method. Updated with my route.

Comment: So are you still having a problem? If yes what are you observing? Is the AJAX call showing anything in `console.log`?